# How to activate the Bootstrap modal-backdrop?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to put up an overlay on my screen while some ajax stuff is running.  Building my own overlay div isn't a big deal, but, since I'm already using Bootstrap, I figure I might as well use its `.modal-backdrop` -- it should already be around, and there's some value to consistency and all that.

The problem is I can't find the right way to do it -- I've tried adding classes to `.modal-backdrop`, or calling `.show()` on it, but it's not working.

Note that I don't want to bring up a whole modal dialog, but just reveal and then hide the backdrop.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Just append a `div` with that class to `body`, then remove it when you're done:

```
// Show the backdrop
$('<div class="modal-backdrop"></div>').appendTo(document.body);

// Remove it (later)
$(".modal-backdrop").remove();
```

Live Example:

```js
$("input").click(function() {
  var bd = $('<div class="modal-backdrop"></div>');
  bd.appendTo(document.body);
  setTimeout(function() {
    bd.remove();
  }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<p>Click the button to get the backdrop for two seconds.</p>
<input type="button" value="Click Me">
```

Comment: @JimMiller: You're welcome! Glad that helped. (Amusingly, I just had reason to learn this about a week ago.)

Comment: You can also do `$('<div class="modal-backdrop"></div>').appendTo(document.body).hide().fadeIn();` if you want the modal backdrop to fade in.

Comment: Are you able to do this to just one part of the page? I want to block out the main content but not the navigation bar of my page

Comment: @Krafty: The JSBin stopped working, don't know why. Made it a Stack Snippet instead.

Comment: Upgrading from bootstrap 3.3.2 to 3.3.4 fixed this issue for me.

Comment: i want this on dropdown button click and deactive with dropdown list

Comment: In Bootstrap 4 your div's class names have to be `modal-backdrop fade in`

Comment: @Hokascha no, it has to be `modal-backdrop fade show` to show a half transparent, black backdrop (or `modal-backdrop show` for no animations).

Comment: @phpguru example is the only one I could get to fade in bootstrap 4. Add the `show` class to make it transparent. Otherwise it fades to black. `$('<div class="modal-backdrop show"></div>').appendTo(document.body).hide().fadeIn();`

Answer (score -4):

Pretty strange, it should work out of the box as the ".modal-backdrop" class is defined top-level in the css.

```
<div class="modal-backdrop"></div>
```

Made a small demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PfBnq/

Comment: This adds an opaque black background.

Comment: To make it semi-transparent and initially invisible, you need to additionally give it the style:  display: none;  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);