# Bootstrap Modal with active background and should not close when clicked outside

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am designing a Modal that stick to the bottom of the Mobile screen to give user some tips. So essentially that (non intrusive kind of) Modal should have two properties,

- Active background (User continue doing what she wants and should not be forced to read)
- Modal should not be closed when tapped/clicked outside

I am able to achieve either of the behaviors but not both at the same time. I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894339/disallow-twitter-bootstrap-modal-window-from-closing) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487052/how-to-activate-the-bootstrap-modal-backdrop) but no luck so far..

I am using Bootstrap 3.3.5. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/718/) is the JSFiddle..

```
<!-- Button to trigger modal -->
<a href="#myModal" role="button" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch Modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-body">        
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
   Modal Test
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add a attribute in your modal trigger `a`  as `data-backdrop="static"` and `data-keyboard="false"`

```
  <a id="idModal" class="modal"  data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" href="#">
```

this will keep it alive if clicked outside the modal

remove this div from the page when you click on a

```
 $("#idModal").on("click",function(){   

   // div that we need to remove 
   //  <div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
        $("div.modal-backdrop").remove();
 })
```

Comment: Well.. I tried that but doesn't seem to be working.. Please check here at http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/718/

Comment: I checked your fiddle its working perfectly there might be some error in your code or your modal might be having any conflicts with other js component, take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/meeneshjain/xwnLc8pa/1/

Comment: In Fiddle, one condition is full-filled and that is, Modal is not getting closed while clicking outside. But background is still disabled.

Comment: In other words, I am not able to write something in the text box when popup is enabled.. I also try with data-backdrop="false"

Comment: then you need some custom code for manipulating the css and the html dom content, see i have made some changes to my answer

Comment: We are getting close.. Black background is gone but still I notice that I am not able to write anything in the text box.. I appreciate your effort btw..