# How to prevent user from interacting with the page when making an ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Im using ajax to allow a user to delete something on my page.

What html/css tricks can i use to prevent the user from clicking on anything on the page. What im after is some sort of transparent overlay with a spinner in the center of my screen.

In ajax i know i can use beforesend and success functions to show and hide the loading.

```
    $.ajax({
            beforeSend : function (){
             $('#loading').show();
            }
            success: function (result) {
            $('#loading').hide();


            }

        });
    }
```

Ive come across these spinners but they are not full overlays which prevents the user from clicking on anything and they are not centered.
http://projects.lukehaas.me/css-loaders/

Comment: If you can use bootstrap then there already an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487052/how-to-activate-the-bootstrap-modal-backdrop) close to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the source of loader in the [LINK](http://projects.lukehaas.me/css-loaders/) you provided in the question, CSS loader is achieved by applying a class to a div. Eg:-

```
<div class="loader">Loading...</div>
```

So, you may do:

```
$.ajax({
  beforeSend : function (){
    $("#some_div_id").addClass("loader");
  },
  success: function (result) {
    $("#some_div_id").removeClass("loader");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

css solution:

```css
body.loading { 
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing is preventing elements from being a target of pointer events using the [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) CSS property:

```
.no-click {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

And then just add this class to elements that should not receive any pointer events (this includes *all* pointer events, like `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` as well). For example, you could add this to the `body` element to prevent all pointer interaction:

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function () {
         $("body").addClass("no-click");
    },
    success: function (result) {
         $("body").removeClass("no-click");
    }
});
```

Comment: This has issues on Internet Explorer. See [stackoverflow.com/questions/17441810](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441810/pointer-events-none-does-not-work-in-ie9-and-ie10)

Answer (score -1):

try toggling a bootstrap modal containing the spinner during the ajax request:

script

```
    function sendRequest(){
        $('#modal').modal('toggle');
        $.ajax({
        success: function (result) {
            $('#modal').modal('hide');
        }

    });

}
```

html

```
<button id="clickButton" onclick="sendRequest()" class="buttonStyle">click me</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
     <div class="loader"></div>
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score -3):

To prevent any users to click anywhere on the page, you need to disable click event handlers.
Here's an example of how you could prevent that:

```html
document.oncontextmenu = new Function("return false"); //No right clicks
document.onclick = new Function("return false"); //No left clicks
```

Comment: Will that work if event is not allowed to bubble by the event handler?

Comment: @TeaCode What ? I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: No, it won't. In cases where an event handler on a child element (basically any element is a child of `document`) prevents propagation, this code will never run.

Comment: This is a dreadful solution given the other ways this can be achieved.

Comment: @webnoob Why do you think that ?

Comment: Because you then have to control adding the events back in again. Adding an overlay to the page is a much better way and also allows adding a loading icon etc. Removing events has it's place but not in this situation IMO.